# IIS allow access to a specific controller but not all website with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, windows-authentication

I have a ASP.NET website set up with Windows Authentication for a specific domain group (MYDOMAIN\MY_SITE_USERS). I want to add a controller with some actions that can be performed from a special Windows account, without access to the rest of the website.

So:

```
~   ==> only MYDOMAIN\MY_SITE_USERS
~/DoSomething ==> only MYDOMAIN\MY_SITE_USERS
~/SpecialAction/Do ==> only MYDOMAIN\SPECIAL_ACCOUNT
```

I've seen other answers (using `location` in Web.Config) for example:

```
<location path="~/SpecialAction/Do">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Deny" users="*"/>
                <add accessType="Allow" users="MYDOMAIN\SPECIAL_ACCOUNT"/>
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

but my the problem is that with the above, then SPECIAL_ACCOUNT can access all the other pages since I need to add to the general:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authorization>
    <allow users="MYDOMAIN\SPECIAL_ACCOUNT" />
    <allow users="MYDOMAIN\MY_SITE_USERS"/>
    <deny users="?" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

otherwise MYDOMAIN\SPECIAL_ACCOUNT can't login at all.

Comment: Can you add a special role or group to the relevant windows users?

Comment: @ste-fu Yes, if it helps I can

Comment: @ste-fu I thought it was a question to understand the scenario. If instead is "have you tried with a role/group" then the answer is Yes I tried, nothing changes

Comment: sorry for the delay I only just saw the notification. I was thinking that you could add a role/group to the "MySiteUsers" but not to "SpecialAccount" and then you could just add the appropriate "Authorize" attribute to your other controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use any approach similar to the following one?

```
public static class ApplicationRoles
{
    public const string SpecialAccount = @"domain\Special Account";
    public const string MySiteUsers = @"domain\My Site Users";
}

[Authorize(Roles = ApplicationRoles.SpecialAccount)] 
public class SpecialAction()
{
    //stuff
}

[Authorize(Roles = ApplicationRoles.MySiteUsers)] 
public class DoSomething()
{
    //stuff
}
```

If you are looking for a web.config based solution, it would be worthy to have a look at [Dynamic Controller/Action Authorization in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.ryanmwright.com/2010/04/25/dynamic-controlleraction-authorization-in-asp-net-mvc/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's definitely a solution to the problem. However I was hoping to find a more general way using just Web.config. Following your approach I would need to use the Authorize attribute on EACH controller/action... lots of work and it can be error prone (If I forget to add it when adding a new controller or action)

Comment: @peval27 I added an update, you might have a look at.

Comment: Thanks for the updated. I'll have a look soon. Upvote is both for questions and answers ;)

Comment: the link you posted is definetly something which could solve the problem. not sure why isn't built in MVC web.config though

Answer (score 1):

Use an action filter on the controllers that require protection.

```
public class FilterAccountsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       string username = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
       //do your logic here for access.

       //if allow no need to do anything

       //else redirect to error page etc?
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                               new RouteValueDictionary
                               {
                                   { "action", "Error" },
                                   { "controller", "Home" },
                                   {"area", ""}
                               });

    }
}
```

Then use like so:

```
[FilterAccounts]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

You could even extend the above to take arguments. If you can shove all your logic into one filter then you only need to remember to add it to all your controllers with the argument needed for it's protection.

```
[FilterAccounts(FilterEnum.OnlySpecialAccount)]
[FilterAccounts(FilterEnum.OnlySiteUsers)]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. This means I need to use the attribute on each controller, not practical... and I was hoping there could be a solution in Web.config so we don't need to hard code groups/identity in the code (which means if you want to change you need a new build). If I can't find a solution, this is going to be my best option though!

Comment: If you want to get more funky you can add the filter globally and use the `ActionExecutingContext` to figure out where in the app you are. This method is discouraged apparently, being a difference between securing routes and controllers.

Comment: it feels weird that there isn't a solution out of the box. it doesn't seem an edge use case! I just want to allow restricted access to a specific bit of the website :)